# having trouble setting $PATH

Tags: paths

I am trying to set the $PATH permanantly for Vault. I have cd to etc and run sudo nano environment. This opens and I have appended my needed path onto the end like this:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/richb201/Vault"

And I save this to environment. I then open a new cli and type echo $PATH but the new path "/home/richb201/Vault" doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See here for the whole story on how to correctly configure the environment system wide or per user: https://www.tecmint.com/set-unset-environment-variables-in-linux/ In your case, I would follow the advice given in the answer posted, so you do not need to be root and it affects your user only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set my path in ~/.profile (ie in your home directory), no sudo necessary. There is already some code in there by default to add ~/bin which you can use as an example. But you will have to log out and in again, not just open a new terminal.